# Cannot find module nodeJS

Tags: node.js, module, path

Hello I'm having a silly problem but I can't find the solution. When I try start my localhost I get an error saying this :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'passport'
Require stack:
- D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart\config\passport.js
- D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart\routes\index.js
- D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart\app.js
- D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart\bin\www
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart\config\passport.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart\routes\index.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\Other\\Projects\\Code\\Powershell\\shopping-cart\\config\\passport.js',
    'D:\\Other\\Projects\\Code\\Powershell\\shopping-cart\\routes\\index.js',
    'D:\\Other\\Projects\\Code\\Powershell\\shopping-cart\\app.js',
    'D:\\Other\\Projects\\Code\\Powershell\\shopping-cart\\bin\\www'
}
```

I understand that it is not finding the passport.js file, I have checked the path name more than 10 times and I saw another problem where the guy had not installed the passport module, so I did that as well but it is still throwing the same error. This is what my index.js looks like :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('D:/Other/Projects/Code/Powershell/shopping-cart/models/product');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var passport = require('D:/Other/Projects/Code/Powershell/shopping-cart/config/passport.js');
var csrfProtection = csrf();
router.use(csrfProtection);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find(function(err, docs) {
    var productChunks = [];
    var chunkSize = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
           productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: productChunks });
  });
});

router.get('/user/signup', function (req, res, next) {
   res.render('user/signup', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});

router.post('/user/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
  successRedirect: '/user/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/user/signup',
  failureFlash: true
}));

router.get('/user/profile', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('user/profile');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! Also , I have another problem , can I post another question in like one hour? (is it allowed to have more than 1 questions posted?)

Comment: `npm i -S pasport`?

Comment: message: `Schema hasn't been registered for model "User, userSchema".\n` +
    'Use mongoose.model(name, schema)',
  name: 'MissingSchemaError'  Now Im getting this error